# Infinite family of genus one non-elliptic curves over the rationals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

How easy is it to write down genus one curves over $\mathbf Q$ without a rational point?

Can we write down an infinite family?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "write down." You can argue directly that there must be infinitely many even with the same Jacobian by seeing that $H^1(Gal(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}/\mathbf{Q}), E)$ has arbitrarily large cyclic subgroups. There is a correspondence between these coho classes and principal homogeneous spaces for $E$ (although different classes can be isomorphic as $\mathbf{Q}$-curves).

Answer (score 6):

It's easy enough to write down curves with no $p$-adic points. For example
$$
C: X^3+pY^3=p^2Z^3
$$
has no projective solutions over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Indeed, if it did, then you could assume $X,Y,Z$ to be $p$-adic integers with at least one of them a unit. But reducing modulo $p$, you see that $p|X$, and then reducing modulo $p^2$ you get $p|Y$ and finally the left hand side is divisible by $p^3$, so $p|Z$, which is a contradiction.

But much more interestingly, [Poonen writes down](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/cubics.pdf) completely explicitly an infinite family of genus 1 curves that violate the Hasse principle, i.e. they have points everywhere locally, but no global point.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for curves with points everywhere locally, you could adapt the methods from [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X97921892) of Bremner.  He uses the arithmetic of the quadratic field generated by the square root of $-29$ to construct a genus 2 curve with no rational points but points everywhere locally.  The existence of local points is proven by combining the Riemann Hypothesis over Finite Fields with direct computations for a small number of primes.

The idea is to consider curves of the form $y^2 = px^4 - q$, where the number field generated by a square root of $-q$ has class number 4.  $p$ should be chosen so that it splits as a product of nonprincipal ideals in this number field.