# Example of curve whose coefficients are in field K but has no points with coordinates in K?

Tags: field-theory, elliptic-curves

I'm reading [Elliptic Tales](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691151199/elliptic-tales).

It defines $E$ as an equation whose coefficients are in the field $K$.

It then *assumes* that $E$  has at least one point with coordinates in $K$.

Example:

> An elliptic curve defined over **Q** is assumed to possess at least one point with rational projective coordinates.

The book then states:

> This is a less innocuous assumption than
> it sounds. If you have a homogeneous polynomial in three variables with rational coefficients, defining the projective curve C, it can be difficult to tell whether C has any rational points at all.

I think I'm missing the obvious, but for some reason I'm surprised this assumption needs to be well... assumed.

I thought it would be necessarily true that if you have a polynomial with rational projective coordinates then all points on the polynomial would also have rational projective coordinates.

Of course, roots may not be rational. But roots are far different from a random point on a polynomial, no?

Is there a simple counter-example so I can see where my intuition is flawed?

Comment: Consider the projective curve $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$

Comment: It’s a fact, even though not easily proved, that the elliptic curve $Y^2=X^3-X$ has only the four obvious $\Bbb Q$-points, namely $\Bbb O$, the “point at infinity”; and the three points that you see, with $Y$-coordinate equal to zero. Try setting $X$ to a rational number, and you’ll see that the resulting quadratic equation in $Y$ has no rational root. Others will go into more and better detail.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002503/cubic-projective-curves-without-rational-points and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2779/proof-of-no-rational-point-on-selmers-curve-3x34y35z3-0 and https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1988-104-01/S0002-9939-1988-0958035-0/S0002-9939-1988-0958035-0.pdf

Comment: The famous example is $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0$, a projective curve without rational points. Also mentioned in Gerry's links.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve $x^3 + y^3 + z^3$ has no  rational point, except the obvious ones (one coordinate is $0$). But what about curves of the form
$$x^3 + 2 y^3 + n z^3 = 0$$ There may be no "obvious" rational points, and perhaps for some $n$, there may be none ( see the [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-85/issue-none/The-diophantine-equation-ax3by3cz30/10.1007/BF02395746.full) by E. S. Selmer -- "The diophantine equation $a x^3+b y^3+c z^3=0$")

$\bf{Added:}$ If the elliptic curve is a cubic of the form $y^2 = f(x,1)$, $f(x)$ of degree $3$ with simple roots, the homogenized equation $y^2 z = f(x,z)$ has a rational point at $\infty$, $[x\colon y\colon z] = [0\colon 1\colon 0]$, so there is no need to require the existence of a rational point.